# Java api public-suffix-list returns a null domain

Tags: java, dns, tld, public-suffix-list

I use an java API to extract the second domain name based on the given URLs.

https://github.com/whois-server-list/public-suffix-list

It based on the `PUBLIC SUFFIX LIST` of Mozilla.

Given codes below:

```
PublicSuffixListFactory factory = new PublicSuffixListFactory();
    PublicSuffixList suffixList = factory.build();
    String[] domainArray = new String[10];
    domainArray[0] = "swcdn.apple.com";
    domainArray[1] = "production-pdt.siriusxm.com";
    domainArray[2] = "audio2.spotify.com";
    domainArray[3] = "a1935.phobos.apple.com";
    domainArray[4] = "r13---sn-ab5l6n7r.c.pack.google.com";
    domainArray[5] = "a132.phobos.apple.com";
    domainArray[6] = "a1736.phobos.apple.com";
    domainArray[7] = "r17---sn-vgqs7n7l.c.android.clients.google.com";
    domainArray[8] = "s4.amazonaws.com";
    domainArray[9] = "s3.amazonaws.com";

    for(String string : domainArray){
        String domain = suffixList.getRegistrableDomain(string);
        System.out.println(domain);
    }
```

I got the following output:

```
apple.com
siriusxm.com
spotify.com
apple.com
google.com
apple.com
apple.com
google.com
amazonaws.com
null
```

It works well for most domains, but for the `s3.amazonaws.com`, it returns null. However for a similar one: `s4.amazonaws.com`, it give the right result. What's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*s3.amazonaws.com* is included in the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat) and therefore considered as not registrable. [`PublicSuffixList.getRegistrableDomain()`](http://whois-server-list.github.io/public-suffix-list/apidocs/de/malkusch/whoisServerList/publicSuffixList/PublicSuffixList.html#getRegistrableDomain%28java.lang.String%29) returns `null` in this case:

> Returns:
>       the registrable domain, null if the domain is not registrable at all

Comment: why a domain included in public suffix list is considered as not registrable? So we can not handle such a domain???

Comment: If you think s3.amazonaws.com should not be included in that list you can ask Mozilla to remove that.